# SonarQube does not see tests in modules

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have multi module project and i need to check it with sonar. So I configured `sonarqube.properties` to scan each modules, it works but without tests. In dashboard I have 0% coverage, although it should be ~70%.

My project similar shown below.

sonarqube.properties

```
sonar.projectKey=test_multilib

sonar.java.binaries=**/*

sonar.modules=lib, child, foo, bar

lib.sonar.projectName=test_multilib:lib
lib.sonar.tests=src/test
lib.sonar.sources=src/main/java

child.sonar.projectName=test_multilib:child
child.sonar.tests=src/test
child.sonar.sources=src/main/java

foo.sonar.projectName=test_multilib:foo
foo.sonar.tests=src/test
foo.sonar.sources=src/main/java

bar.sonar.projectName=test_multilib:bar
bar.sonar.tests=src/test
bar.sonar.sources=src/main/java
```